# Actionscript 3 XML Get All Elements By Order Not Element Name

Tags: xml, actionscript

I've been able to accomplish this in other languages, but am having trouble in AS3.

I have an XML file structured like:

```
<person>
    <q0>answer1</q0>
    <q1>answer2></q1>
</person>
```

And so on for multiple people who are all asked the same 13 questions (q0 - q12).

I am trying to push these into an array in action script like so:

```
function push_array(e:Event):void 
{
    flashmo_xml = XML(e.target.data);
    total = flashmo_xml.item.length();

    for( i = 0; i < total; i++ )
    {
        flashmo_item_list.push( {
            title: questions[i], 
            description: flashmo_xml.item[i].("q" + i).toString()
        } );
    }
    create_item_list();
}
```

(NOTE: the array questions[] contains strings of all the questions and the xml file contains the answers in case that wasn't clear)

However this is not working. I know there must be a way to do this rather than getting all the questions individually without a for() loop. Thanks in advance for any help =D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`total = flashmo_xml.children().length();` and then `flashmo_xml["q" + i]`, or `flashmo_xml.child(i)` if you prefer, in the loop should work if the XML is like in your example.

ActionScript 3 uses [E4X, "ECMAScript for XML"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript_for_XML), which can feel a bit different compared to other languages XML implementations, but is quite nice to use when you get the hang of it.

Comment: thanks and thanks for the info on ecmascript, def gonna read up on that :)